# How to fix error "File "/.../google/cloud/storage/_http.py", line 33, in __init__ TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

The above mentioned error occurred while trying to run a cloud function in Google Cloud Platform. The error occurred in its main.py written in python in the line "storage_client=storage.Client()"

I have also checked the github repository for google-cloud-python/storage/google/cloud/storage/_http.py  line 33 where it is showing error but I have done nothing with those variables anywhere, I reckon

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hey Marghoob, could you please share a snippet of the code that you are running? Also, could you please confirm if you are trying to deploy your application from a Compute Engine instance or an App Engine instance?

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced this same issue--

Short answer-- upgrade the google-cloud-core package: e.g. in my case I had 
`google-cloud-core==0.29.1`

Upgrading to version 1.0.2 solved my issue:

`pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-core==1.0.2`

For me, this arose from installing all my python packages from a requirements.txt file, which had explicit versions.  Sometime later, I must have upgraded and the packages did not stay aligned.

Comment: I had similar issues, but in my case verion of google-cloud-core wasn't mentioned in requirements.txt, as result my google function used unknown for me version of core and raised the same exception.